# AG-Grid Column Overlapping

Tags: ag-grid

I'm having a spot of trouble with ag-grid enterprise. I have a grid with groups that function sort of like a folder tree. However, the name column overlaps with the rest of the columns. This is especially apparent when resizing the columns. No other column overlaps like this. What could be causing this?

[image: An ag-grid with a couple of columns. The text from the initial column is going outside of the column bounds and overlapping with text in other columns]

Comment: do you use a custom renderer for your name column ? if yes make sure your renderer has a fixed max-width

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue fixed itself when we pinned the column to the left using `pinned: left`. Doesn't make much sense to me personally but that is how we got around it.

EDIT: Further looked into it. It was a styling issue. We were setting display to flex.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Double check your ColDefs.
Someone had accidently set the width:0 to the first column and were seeing this.

Not sure about col resize as we didn't have that enabled. Still if minWidth is set (which someone could have for mobile users), it could cause this.

```
ColDef params:

maxWidth
width
minWidth
```